Bad Request - Invalid Hostname whenever trying to use IP address
We have an IIS server that hosts dozens of different websites and services. As of this morning, all sites hosted on this server are suddenly returning a Bad Request - Invalid Hostname response when they are accessed via IP address.
When sites are accessed via a hostname (localhost or through an SSL offloader/Web Application Firewall with the host header passed).
In IIS all sites are configured to listen http with IP address All Unassigned and a custom port with the Host name blank.
The server did reboot to apply a windows update this morning (KB5048661) but that update does not appear to impact IIS, multiple other servers in our environment have it applied without seeing the same issue, and rolling back the update did not resolve the issue so I'm not thinking that's the source.
We've attempted to recreate a site from scratch and still receive the Invalid Hostname error.
The httperr log is dutifully reporting the 400 Hostname responses:
2024-12-24 13:54:13 172.x.x.x 52900 172.x.x.x 18161 HTTP/1.1 POST /xxxx - 400 - Hostname W3SvcInspection
but I'm not sure where to get more information on why or what it's trying to match.
I've tried comparing configurations between this server and other servers in the same environment but cannot see any difference and am stuck trying to troubleshoot further on why IIS is returning this error suddenly.
More from the httperr log:
2024-12-24 09:15:37 172.16.33.16 54707 172.16.33.16 18090 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2024-12-24 09:16:42 172.16.33.16 54731 172.16.33.16 18245 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2024-12-24 09:25:45 172.16.33.16 54819 172.16.33.16 18090 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2024-12-24 09:40:13
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri streamid sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2024-12-24 09:40:13 172.16.33.16 49756 172.16.33.16 18041 HTTP/1.1 POST /CoreWHWS.asmx - 400 - Hostname W3SvcInspection
2024-12-24 09:40:14 172.16.33.1 55206 172.16.33.16 18246 HTTP/1.1 GET /WebKiosk/Number614086 - 400 - Hostname W3SvcInspection
2024-12-24 09:40:23 172.16.33.1 55274 172.16.33.16 18246 HTTP/1.1 GET /WebKiosk/Number614086 - 400 - Hostname W3SvcInspection
2024-12-24 09:40:30 172.16.33.1 55308 172.16.33.16 18246 HTTP/1.1 GET /WebKiosk/Number614086 - 400 - Hostname W3SvcInspection

And just to confirm:
The following URL works fine: http://localhost:18041/CoreWHWS.asmx
The following URLs return an invalid hostname: http://127.0.0.1:18041/CoreWHWS.asmx
http://172.16.33.16:18041/CoreWHWS.asmx
The bindings are set to All Unassigned IPs with the hostname field blank. This is happening with every single site hosted on this server, so appears to be some sort of IIS wide issue versus a specific binding issue.

You have to post the httperr log entry entirely and well formatted. Besides, anything else you installed on this server that hooks to Windows HTTP API?

Added more HTTP Err lines and formatted.
The first 3 are random timeouts from prior to the reboot. The ones after that are what we've been seeing since.
Nothing I am aware of should hook the Windows HTTP API differently, especially between when it was working and now.

The reason I think is the multiple site definition with the same port. If there are multiple web sites with the same IP address and port number, you should differentiate them with host header field. The hostname in the binding for each site with the same IP & port no. should be filled with another DNS name and browser URL  should be the same (host part) while accessing that site.

@ErkinD39 All sites have their own unique ports. I've done some troubleshooting with help from another forum and it appears the source of the issue is the W3SvcInspection that's somehow listening on all ports that IIS is. I'm trying to troubleshoot what that is as googling is yielding basically zero results for it.

Did you try defining site names (FQDNs) in hosts file for each site and defining host header the same corresponding FQDN for each web site binding ? Then each site should be connected as exactly the same host header (FQDN).

HTTP.sys isn't compatible with the ASP.NET Core Module and can't be used with IIS or IIS Express.  Pls see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-9.0&preserve-view=true and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/urlprefix-strings . You may run the cmd netsh http show urlacl .

Everything on the server should be hosted via IIS, not HTTP.sys
When comparing the output of netsh http show urlacl they are fully identical between a working server and the one with this issue.

Does netsh show http servicestate output include registered URLs as http://*:80 ? Could you test with a simpler page like start page .htm etc? Does ping -a  give the expected result?

This occurs with ultra simple .html pages as well.
As part of separate troubleshoot I saw the netsh http show servicestate includes a site where the Request queue name is W3SvcInspection and the registered URLs are all of the URLs that any site is set up as on IIS. So somehow this W3SvcInspection is coming in and listening on all URLs and doing something. I've been completely unable to find what W3SvcInspection is though. The best is being able to trace it to a string occuring in iisw3adm.dll but I can't find information on what it does or how it might be enabled, disabled or configured.
